# What are the worst-case time bounds for each operation on a Fibonacci heap?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity, fibonacci-heap

Fibonacci heaps are efficient in an *amortized* sense, but how efficient are they in the worst case? Specifically, what is the worst-case time complexity of each of these operations on an n-node Fibonacci heap?

- find min
- delete-min
- insert
- decrease-key
- merge

Comment: have you check this in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap

Comment: Of course, and I still cant find out NOT AMORTIZED complexity. Maybe you can show me fragment in wiki with that?

Comment: Given an implementation, could you find it yourself? Next, _what_ is the main obstacle to making it faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The find-min operation on a Fibonacci heap always takes worst-case O(1) time. There's always a pointer maintained that directly points to that object.

The cost of a delete-min, in the worst-case, takes time Θ(n). To see this, imagine starting with an empty heap and doing a series of n insertions into it. Each node will be stored in its own tree, and doing a delete-min the heap will coalesce all these objects into O(log n) trees, requiring Θ(n) work to visit all the nodes at least once.

The cost of an insertion is worst-case O(1); this is just creating a single node and adding it to the list. A merge is similarly O(1) since it just splices two lists together.

The cost of a decrease-key in the worst case is Θ(n). It's possible to build a degenerate Fibonacci heap in which all the elements are stored in a single tree consisting of a linked list of n marked nodes. Doing a decrease-key on the bottommost node then triggers a run of cascading cuts that will convert the tree into n independent nodes.

Comment: Could You explain how to build a FIB head where all elements are stored in a single tree, which is of height n? I thought that every tree has O(logn) height.

Comment: @Michocio Sure! See [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300256/how-to-show-fibonacci-heap-with-n-nodes-can-have-height-n/14300462#14300462) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I almost agree with the great answer from @templatetypedef.

There cannot be a tree of a classical Fibonacci heap with $n$ marked nodes. This would mean that the height of the tree is O(n), but since for each subtree of rank $k$ its children are of ranks $\geq 0, \geq 1, ... , \geq k-1$. It is easy to see that the depth of the tree is at most O(logn). And therefore a single Decrease-key operation can cost O(logn).

I checked [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300256/how-to-show-fibonacci-heap-with-n-nodes-can-have-height-n/14300462#14300462), and it takes some modification of the Fibonacci heap, as it has marked node in the root list and does operation which do not belong to the Fibonacci heap.